# LTMorphingLabel Swift4 Error

Tags: swift, swift4

I get below error.

Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'LTEmitterConfigureClosure?' (aka 'Optional<(CAEmitterLayer, CAEmitterCell) -> ()>')

How can i fix it?

```
self.emitterView.createEmitter(
                "fragments",
                particleName: "Fragment",
                duration: 0.6
                ) {_ in}.update { (layer, _) in
                    if progress > end {
                        layer.birthRate = 0
                    }
                }.play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace trailing closure `{_ in}` with `configureClosure: nil`, ie.

```
self.emitterView.createEmitter(
                "fragments",
                particleName: "Fragment",
                duration: 0.6,
                configureClosure: nil).update { (layer, _) in
                    if progress > end {
                        layer.birthRate = 0
                    }
                }.play()
```